# Get "Microsoft JScript runtime error" when add SignalR to MainSite.Master

Tags: signalr

Please help me. Our aps.net web application is using SignalR as the notifier, it uses a hub and works well for one page but when I added these lines of code to MainSite.Master:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function (jQuery) {
        var notifyHub = jQuery.connection.notificationHub;

        jQuery.connection.hub.start();
    });
</script>
```

Visual Studio throw the error message:

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'transports': object is null or undefined

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem by replacing:

```
jQuery.connection.hub.start();
```

by

```
$.connection.hub.start({ transport: ['webSockets', 'serverSentEvents', 'longPolling'] });
```

Comment: You should be able to get away with just $.connection.hub.start();